# What are the limitations on number of emails that can be sent by our power automate flow which is running under E1 license (low performance profile)

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, licensing, service-account

We have a scheduled flow flow which run under a service account that have E1 license (low performance profile), and the scheduled flow sends email using the "Send an Email V2", as follow:-

[image]

so, my question is how many emails our scheduled flow can send per run or per minute or per day?

Thanks

Comment: 300 API calls per connection in 60 **seconds** - this is the throttling limit for Outlook connector in Power automate.

Comment: @GaneshSanap thanks for the reply. but in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#sending-limits it is saying the limitation is 30 message per minute .. not sure